# MongoDB : Older records of Mongo DB collection doesn't got necessary keys in them

Tags: mongodb

These are 3 sample records present in my Mongo DB employees Collection .

If you can observe , one field named "**country**" is missing in one of the record shown below .

```
db.employees.find().pretty()

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("513331a227a414395af00904"),
        "name" : "Ravi",
        "age" : "21",
        "dept" : "DEV",
        "country" : "IND"
}


{
        "_id" : ObjectId("513331e627a414395af00905"),
        "name" : "Pavan",
        "age" : "23",
        "dept" : "DEV"
}

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("513331e627a414395af00907"),
        "name" : "Saagy",
        "age" : "22",
        "dept" : "DEV",
        "country" : "US"
}
```

I am working on a existing Mongo DB where some keys  may not be present in older records in the collection as shown in above records .

Right now with below code i am getting only one record as response as country key is not present in another Record .

```
    DBCollection mycollection = db.getCollection("employees");
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("dept", "DEV");
    query.put("country", "IND");

    DBCursor cursor = mycollection.find(query);

    while (cursor.hasNext()) 
    {
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }
```

My requirement is that ,  if country key is not present then  it should be treated as IND and  should be also included in the response .

Is this possible ??

Please let me know .

**Updated Part**

I have tried using $exists , but i am getting an Exception

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException {
        Mongo mongo = new Mongo();
        DB db = mongo.getDB("test");
        DBCollection mycollection = db.getCollection("employees");

        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("dept", "DEV");
        query.put("country", "IND");
        DBObject subquery = new BasicDBObject("country", new BasicDBObject("$exists", false));

        DBCursor cursor = mycollection.find(query,subquery);

        while (cursor.hasNext()) 
        {
        System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }




    }



Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoException: Unsupported projection option: $exists
    at com.mongodb.MongoException.parse(MongoException.java:82)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:314)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:295)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:368)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:459)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:484)
    at com.Test.main(Test.java:26)
```

Comment: Have you tried [$or](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/or/) and [$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/) for your query? If you're not using an object layer that provides default values when null, I'd suggest just adding the logic to your code rather than making the DB do the busy work.

Comment: Thanks for the $or and $exists , i don't about them earlier . I will try and post if i face any issue regarding it .

Comment: Thanks i can manage this with $exists m but right now i am getting an Exception , please see the Updated Part in my question .

Comment: `$exists` is not a projection operator, it's a query operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this issue with a combination of $or and $exists. This should be about right:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException {
    Mongo mongo = new Mongo();
    DB db = mongo.getDB("test");
    DBCollection mycollection = db.getCollection("employees");

    DBObject clause1 = new BasicDBObject("country", "IND");  
    DBObject clause2 = new BasicDBObject("$exists", false);    
    BasicDBList or = new BasicDBList();
    or.add(clause1);
    or.add(clause2);

    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("dept", "DEV");
    query.put("$or", or);

    DBCursor cursor = mycollection.find(query);

    while (cursor.hasNext()) 
    {
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }




}
```